# eclipse link duplicate keys strange error

Tags: java, database, jpa, eclipselink

when i creating data to the first entity(customer1) the data was created successfully 
but when I want to create the data to the second entity Im getting the following error.
we are generating this two entities in **two different packages** with different table annotation name so I don't understand why im getting this error .
we also create **different persistence-unit** name for every entity...
what could be the reason for this error ?

the error is in the commit

```
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
```

> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The
>   statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key
>   value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified
>   by 'SQL130407132754180' defined on 'customer02'. Error Code: 20000
>   Call: INSERT INTO customer02(CUSTOMER, NOTE, BUYERID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
>   bind => [3 parameters bound] Query:
>   InsertObjectQuery(prod2.customer02@7fe4bdcc)

entity 1 customer in package ...**customer01**

```
package prod1;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer01")
public class Customer
{

  @Id
  @Column(name="customer_number")
  private String customer;
  private String Note;
  private String BuyerId;
```

entity 2 customer in package ...**customer02**

```
package prod2;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer02")
public class Customer
{

  @Id
  @Column(name="customer_number")
  private String customer;
  private String Note;
  private String BuyerId;
```

the persistence unit is

```
-<persistence-unit name="prod1">
<class>prod1.customer01</class>-
<properties><property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" 
value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE"/>
</properties></persistence-unit>-

-<persistence-unit name="prod2">
<class>prod2.customer02</class>-
<properties><property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" 
value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE"/>
</properties></persistence-unit>-
```

Comment: IMO, this is not an Eclipse link issue as it seems eclipse link just passes an SQL exception. Can you show the database constraint `SQL130407132754180`? And are you sure that there aren't any dups in customer02?

Comment: no there is no dumps in customer02 I have debug the code,how can i show the database constraint ?how i find it?

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: Hana which is SAP database

Comment: Then check the database (I'm not familiar with HANA), a constraint with the given ID should exist...

Comment: Turn on logging to see what exactly is getting put into the db and how the sequence is assigned: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging. Try checking what is in the customer02 table as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be using sequencing, so how are your ID values assigned?  Your app must be setting them and is responsible for picking unique ones.

Answer (score 0):

The annotations shown do not have sequencing defined for the IDs.  Try adding @GeneratedValue to have the provider assign them for you.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how should I manage it if for example for entity one there is id's from 1-10 how should I know the Id's when I go to generated entity2,if i dont know them I guess i will get the same error...

Comment: If you let the provider handle sequencing, it will assign values sequentially, and increment the counter so the dont get reassigned